# Save Properties to XML without header

Tags: java, xml, properties

Properties class has very nice methods storeToXml and loadFromXml. But store adds header, so xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
 <properties>
  <entry key="key">value</entry>
 </properties>
```

I don't want to have this header, because i store it in database to make it xpath serchable. And also i want to load in to Properties object. Have anyone good ideas? Thanks

Comment: Header will not impact xpath as it is meta data only.

Comment: But sqlserver says that Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support.

Comment: Thanks all, I really needed to use CONVERT function of sql server, it removes dtd and header and when i load it, it converts to properties properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither XPath nor `Properties.loadFromXml()` care for the header. So this should work as it is.

If it's really a problem, then write the result to a `StringWriter` or `ByteArrayOutputStream` and remove anything before `<properties>`. But that might actually cause errors loading the XML since the doctype is now missing.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the header :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("filename")));
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("filename_out")));
String line;
int counter = 0;

while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
    if(counter > 0){
    wr.write(line.trim());
    }
    counter++;
}
wr.close();
br.close();
```

Comment: this code assumes an implementation detail - that there are line breaks in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("A.a", "BB");
p.put("A.b", "BB");
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
p.storeToXML(bout, "Commnet!");
String sp = new String(bout.toByteArray());
sp = sp.substring(sp.indexOf('\n', sp.indexOf('\n') + 1) + 1);
System.out.println(sp);
```

It will give you following result:

```
<properties>
<comment>COmmnet!</comment>
<entry key="A.b">BB</entry>
<entry key="A.a">BB</entry>
</properties>
```

Comment: And then when loading back to Properties I need to add header back?

Comment: this code assumes an implementation detail - that there are line breaks in the XML. There is also an encoding bug in the code that assumes (wrongly) that the default system encoding was used to write the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform this xml using a xslt that removes the doctype declaration and so store the output in database.

```
public class XMLTransform {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
      StreamSource source = new StreamSource("your xml");
      StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource("your xslt");

      TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(stylesource);

      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("your xml output file"));
      transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that you write the data to XML, then parse it, then write it again. This'll work, but may impact performance. Also, something else will need to be done to remove the DTD declaration (e.g. use an XSLT template, or a StAX filter result.)

Comment: It's true, he has to write a xslt template to remove the dtd declaration as I wrote above, but I supposed that he had to store the xml file output in a xml db (e.g. eXist db) with this approch he can store the file directly under the db subdirectory, avoiding a passage that in every case he should have done.

Comment: there may also be issues with the transformer and [End-of-Line handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends). `Properties.storeToXML` will preserve characters like `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that [properties.dtd](http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd) is so trivial, write and parse the XML yourself.

Output:

```
  private static String toXml(Properties props) throws XMLStreamException {
    Writer buffer = new StringWriter();
    XMLStreamWriter xml = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory()
        .createXMLStreamWriter(buffer);
    xml.writeStartElement("properties");
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : props.entrySet()) {
      xml.writeStartElement("entry");
      xml.writeAttribute("key", entry.getKey()
          .toString());
      xml.writeCharacters(entry.getValue()
          .toString());
      xml.writeEndElement();
    }
    xml.writeEndElement();
    return buffer.toString();
  }
```

Input:

```
  private static Properties fromXml(String xml) throws XPathException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    NodeList entries =
        (NodeList) XPathFactory.newInstance()
            .newXPath()
            .evaluate("//entry", new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)),
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.getLength(); i++) {
      Node entry = entries.item(i);
      props.setProperty(entry.getAttributes()
          .getNamedItem("key")
          .getNodeValue(), entry.getTextContent());
    }
    return props;
  }
```

*I'm assuming you want data as the default JDBC mapping - String.*

Comment: I should note that there is a weakness in my implementation - it will not preserve whitespace - this can be demonstrated with key value pairs: `"\r"`=`"\r"`. As per the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends), newlines are transformed to `\n`.